# JavaScript date.setMilliseconds strange behavior?

Tags: javascript

Why does this happen -

```
var date   =  new Date('2015-10-24T23:31:04.181Z');
date.toISOString(); // "2015-10-24T23:31:04.181Z"
date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + 1);
date.toISOString(); // "2015-10-24T22:31:04.182Z"
```

- The HOUR has moved one back (23 -> 22)
- **Works fine with other dates**

Is it a time zone issue ? Why doesn't it happen with all date values ?

Thanks

Comment: Chrome & Node.js, My time zone is +2 , try this : https://jsfiddle.net/eeqo9ke9/1/

Comment: I'm on Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit) / Linux

Comment: Replicated with Chrome on Windows using Jerusalem as my timezone. Interestingly, the TZ offset goes from -120 to -180 after adding that millisecond: https://jsfiddle.net/eeqo9ke9/2/

Comment: Thanks ! how'd you guess Jerusalem ? :)

Comment: I started with Athens/Bucharest and then picked another at random. Got lucky with the second one. :-)

Comment: Absolutely fascinating question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's daylight savings time, in a really non-obvious way. :-)

2015-10-24T23:31:04.181Z in Jerusalem is Oct 25 2015 01:31:04 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time) on the date/time when DST ends and the clocks go back ([reference](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/jerusalem)). Specifically, it's within the Groundhog Hour: There are two 01:31:04s that day, first the one in summer time, then the one an hour later in standard time.

You're using `setMilliseconds`, which is a *local time* function. As you probably know, JavaScript's `Date` is smart about handling rollover between date fields (although there is no rollover in this particular case), and so the logic of `setMilliseconds` has to handle allowing for possible rollover. This is [detailed in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.setmilliseconds), but fundamentally it takes the current time value (milliseconds since The Epoch), makes a local date/time out of it, does the work, and then has to turn that local date/time back into a new time value.

But here's where the problem kicks in: Those two 01:31:04s that day. V8 has to choose one when determining the real date/time. It chooses the one in summer time, which is an hour earlier than your original date/time.

If you use `setUTCMilliseconds`, this doesn't happen, because there's no round-trip to local time.

Moral of the story: If you're working in UTC, work exclusively in UTC. :-)